# android gps location in service off if device sleep

Tags: android, service, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I need to update the location through GPS/Network in the background even when the phone is in sleep. 
I implement android service to archive that goal. But the problem is when I put device in sleep, i notify that the [GPS ICON](https://community.sprint.com/baw/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-368119-23382/Epic_GPS_Issue1-resized.png) in notification bar gone away as location update not working anymore.

How can I keep GPS/Network location update in such circumstance?

P/S: I use [FusedLocationAPI](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) and foreground service. Thanks in advance. 
Please note that GPS-ICON image only mention icon in notification bar, I still keep GPS provider turn on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should aquire a wake lock:

```
    //in onCreate of your service
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    cpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "gps_service");
    cpuWakeLock.acquire();

    // Release in onDestroy of your service
    if (cpuWakeLock.isHeld())
      cpuWakeLock.release();
```

and add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Above is good if you need continuous location updates, but if you need locations only from time to time then look into: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll

Comment: I added your code with excitement as this looks like it should work. However I stop seeing onLocationChanged() calls as soon as I turn off the screen, and they don't start again until I unlock the screen.

Comment: You may try disabling battery optimizations on your device for your app, also do you have foreground service?